# Is using implied data in a message to compute a CRC a good design strategy?

Tags: udp, protocols, message, crc

We are sending UDP messages from one device to another. There is a timestamp in the message and transmitted in a 16 bit field. The receiver keeps track of the number of times the field "rolls over" so that time spans that require more than 16 bits can be tracked. The protocol designer has decided that we should use the entire 32 bit timestamp to compute the CRC for the message. Is this a good idea? Note that we have a message period that is much smaller than the "roll over" period.

Comment: Not a good design. Badly mangling data transmission layer (integrity of payload) with application logic (overflow of timer). - What if the CRC check fails? Was the payload corrupted (-> retry/ignore) or did the timers drift apart? No way of telling. - Why not explicitly transmit the full timestamp as part of the payload?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are apparently in control of the messages, you should just transmit the 32-bit timestamp in the message.

What is the size of the CRC? If it is a 16-bit CRC, you could forgo the error detection function completely and solve the equations to get the missing 16-bits of the timestamp from the transmitted message and the CRC. But if you're going to do that, why not just send the other 16-bits of the timestamp directly in the CRC field, instead of a CRC?

If it is a 32-bit CRC, you could again solve, and be left with 16-bits of "strength" in the error detection, instead of 32. Again, one would have to ask why you wouldn't just send the other 16-bits of the timestamp and put a 16-bit CRC in what remains.

Or if you can change the length of the message, just add the missing 16 bits of timestamp, leaving the CRC and its error-detection capability intact.

Comment: It's a 24-bit CRC. I think the protocol designer was thinking that the system will catch an additional failure mode, i.e. an error in the computation of the roll-over. The problem that I see is that the communications become paralyzed in the case of an error in the roll-over computation. Checking roll-over with a simple comparison in magnitude fails when UDP packets arrive out of order, so I think it's a flaw in the design. But I want to hear what people think.